# Find_between function with indexed output?

Tags: python

I'd like to use the `find_between` function to retrieve index-able values from a specific web server.

I'm using the `requests` module to gather some source code from a specific website seen on line 18:

```
response = requests.get("https://www.shodan.io/search?query=Server%3A+SQ-WEBCAM")
```

and I'd like to call the `find_between` function to retrieve all the values (all items on page each item represented by the incrementing value of 'n') with the specified `find_between` parameters:

```
x = find_between(response.content,'/></a><a href="/host/','">---')
```

Anyone know how to pull this off?

```
import sys
import requests
from time import sleep

# Find between page tags on page.
def find_between( s, tag1, tag2 ):
    try:
        start = s.index( tag1 ) + len( tag1 )
        end = s.index( tag2, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

def main():
    # Default value for 'n' index value (item on page) is 0
    n = 0

    # Enter the command 'go' to start
    cmd = raw_input("Enter Command: ")
    if cmd == "go":
        print "go!"

        # Go to this page for page item gathering.
        response = requests.get("https://www.shodan.io/search?query=Server%3A+SQ-WEBCAM")

        # Initial source output...
        print response.content

        # Find between value of 'x' sources between two tags
        x = find_between(response.content,'/></a><a href="/host/','">---')
        while(True):

            # Wait one second before continuing...
            sleep(1)
            n = n + 1

            # Display find_between data in 'x'
            print "\nindex: %s\n\n%s\n" % (n, x)

    # Enter 'exit' to exit script
    if cmd == "exit":
        sys.exit()

# Recursive function call
while(True):
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things in your code appear to need addressing:

1. The value of `x` is set outside (before) your `while` loop, so the loop increments the index `n` but prints the same text over and over because `x` never changes.
2. `find_between()` returns only a single match, and you want all matches.
3. Your `while` loop never ends.

Suggestions:

1. Put the call to `find_between()` inside the `while` loop.
2. Each successive time you call `find_between()`, pass it only the portion of the text following the previous match.
3. Exit the `while` loop when `find_between()` finds no match.

Something like this:

```
text_to_search = response.content
while(True):
    # Find between value of 'x' sources between two tags
    x = find_between(text_to_search, '/></a><a href="/host/', '">---')
    if not x:
        break

    # Wait one second before continuing...
    sleep(1)

    # Increment 'n' for index value of item on page
    n = n + 1

    # Display find_between data in 'x'
    print "\nindex: %s\n\n%s\n" % (n, x)

    # Remove text already searched
    found_text_pos = text_to_search.index(x) + len(x)
    text_to_search = text_to_search[found_text_pos:]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I'd vote your answer up, but I don't have enough reputation points yet.. =/

Comment: Thanks again for figuring out what I was trying to do! Thanks B!